# AutoCAD.PlotToPDF+prod Last Page Missing From Resulting PDF

Tags: autodesk-forge

We're using the shared Forge activity "AutoCAD.PlotToPDF+prod" to get back a plotted DWG in a PDF file, but the resulting PDF is missing the last layout from the DWG. However, there see to be some cases where the last page does get included. There are no obvious differences between the DWGs that include the last page when plotted to PDF and those who don't. Is there any reason why these shared Forge activity wouldn't include the last layout from the source DWG?

This is something that's holding us up from completing a large feature implementation before deploying it to production, so we'd like to find out if we're not going to be able to use the shared activity to make this work so that we can implement a work-around and prevent missing the deadline for delivery.

Thanks in advance.

[Here](https://minicadstaticfiles.blob.core.windows.net/staticfiles/MB_102821_A.zip?sv=2020-04-08&st=2021-10-28T12%3A37%3A44Z&se=2021-11-29T13%3A37%3A00Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=zJvVucCJ9Fcox7LXx8K3Y%2FvOE45M0jPEf3eBEaWCr%2FI%3D) is an example of the input versus output.

Comment: Can you share few drawings where this is happening ?

Comment: Added link above.

Answer (score 0):

The provided drawing is dependent on external reference "background.bmp" as overlay, Forge Design Automation is not aware of the dependent reference, you need to provide that as well.
If your drawing depends on external files, you need to zip them and send, and make sure to provide path of main drawing that to be processed in `pathInZip` argument of workitem.

For example

```
{
  "activityId": "AutoCAD.PlotToPDF+prod",
  "arguments": {
    "HostDwg": {
      "localName": "Outputs",
      "pathInZip": "Output.dwg",
      "url": "downloadUrl",
      "verb": "get"
    },
    "Result": {
      "url": "uploadUrl",
      "verb": "put"
    }
  }
}
```